# How do I make two styles in a stylesheet inherit the same style

Tags: stylesheet

Specifically I want different versions of 'Item1Numbered'. For example one with a frame and another with a background colour. How is that done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["ParentStyle"]` as an option to the `StyleData` of your new style (in the stylesheet), where `"ParentStyle"` is whatever you want to inherit from.

In your case, go to `Format > Edit Stylesheet` and add the following styles:

```
Cell[
    StyleData["MyItemStyle1", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["ItemNumbered"]],
    CellFrame -> True
]

Cell[
    StyleData["MyItemStyle2", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["ItemNumbered"]],
    Background -> GrayLevel[0.8]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make the frame cover the number and make the colour cover all of the inside of the frame and not just the number and the text?

Comment: @Sofic Not directly, but it is possible with some fiddling with the `CellDingbat`. The default definition for number is `CellDingbat->Cell[
   TextData[{
     CounterBox["ItemNumbered"], "."}], FontWeight -> "Bold"]`, which is inherited from `ItemNumbered`. Now if you add `CellFrame -> True` also to the `Cell` used in `CellDingbat`, you will get a frame around the number. However, the two frames now overlap. To resolve this, you'll have to manually fiddle with the `CellMargins` (the left margin for the main cell and the right margin for the dingbat cell) to get a good appearance.